# Optimization of a noisy loss function

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, loss-functions, julia

I'm trying to optimize a noisy loss function (experimental) where the absolute value of the gradient changes significantly depending on the direction taken. In other words, some parameters have a larger influence than others, but all are important. What variant of gradient descent is recommended to use in this case?

To provide a little more context. My objective is to define a loss function that would measure, so to speak, the convergence of the model towards a uniform data distribution.

I generate K random fictitious observations and compare how many of them are smaller than the true data in the training set. In other words, the model generates K simulations, and we determine the number of simulations where the generated data is smaller than the actual data. If the model is well trained, this distribution should converge to a uniform distribution.

However, since the resulting histogram is not differentiable, I needed to approximate this idea using compositions of continuous differentiable functions. The code (in Julia) would be something like this.

```
η = 0.1; num_epochs = 100; n_samples = 1000
optim = Flux.setup(Flux.Adam(η), model)
losses = []
l = CustomLoss(2)
for epoch in 1:num_epochs
    loss, grads = Flux.withgradient(model) do m
        aₖ = zeros(l.K+1)
        for _ in 1:n_samples
            x = rand(Normal(μ, stddev), l.K)
            yₖ = m(x')
            y = target(rand(Normal(μ, stddev)))
           aₖ += generate_aₖ(l, yₖ, y)
        end
        scalar_diff(l, aₖ ./ sum(aₖ))
    end
    Flux.update!(optim, model, grads[1])
    push!(losses, loss)
end
```

So, `generate_aₖ(l, yₖ, y)` would return a vector of size `K+1`, where the element at index k is close to 1 if y is greater than `k` elements of the vector `yₖ`.

Finally, scalar_diff calculates the squared difference between the calculated `aₖ` and the uniform distribution.

After studying the cost function for the simplest case I could think of (learning the parameters of a line `m*x + b`), I see that indeed, the minimum is where it should be. However, the function is relatively noisy, and furthermore (as is evident on the other hand) it decreases very rapidly along the parameter `m` axis compared to the parameter `b` axis.

[image]

Comment: You will get better answers at https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please put a lot more detail of your actual problem. Eg what are you actually optimising g. What is the loss function ( do you even have an analytic gradient or is it computed by difference...) is it costly to estimate the loss function ( eg more experiments)....

Comment: “What variant of gradient descent” is a loaded question. Not necessary gradient descent is an answer at all, but you need to give us more details.

Comment: Stochastic approximation algorithms were designed for this; you might want to check out SPSA (https://www.jhuapl.edu/SPSA/PDF-SPSA/Spall_An_Overview.PDF, https://www.jhuapl.edu/SPSA/) for one such approach that I've used with great success.